# How to get the calling method properties in c#

Tags: c#, reflection, exception

I am currently writing an Error logger for my application, and basically what I am interested in, is when handling the exception, I invoke a function *CreateLogEntry(...)* from my logging class.
The idea is, I want *CreateLogEntry(...)* to know it was called from within a method *BadFunction(...)* and retrieve its parameters as part of the logging process.

Now I already did some homework (I guess not enough though :S), and I am sure my solution lies in the *System.Reflection*, and already found some examples on how to enumerate all functions within a class (http://www.csharp-examples.net/get-method-names/). 
But would it be possible to get the name of the function that creating that exception.

Ex (what I got):

```
    public string GetCurrentMode()
    {
        string currentMode = "";

        try
        {
            currentMode = _host.Mode.ToString();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Common.MorpheeException me = new Common.MorpheeException();

            me.MethodName = "GetCurrentMode";
            me.NameSpace = "MorpheeScript";
            me.ErrorNumber = 0;
            me.ErrorDescription = ex.Message;
            me.StackTrace = ex.StackTrace;

            throw new FaultException<Common.MorpheeException>(me);
        }

        return currentMode;
    }
```

What I want to have:

```
        public string GetCurrentMode()
    {
        string currentMode = "";

        try
        {
            currentMode = _host.Mode.ToString();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Common.MorpheeException me = new Common.MorpheeException(ex);

            // Here me should know that it is called from GetCurrentMode() and
            // retrieve the parameters if there are any
            throw new FaultException<Common.MorpheeException>(me);
        }

        return currentMode;
    }
```

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `MorpheeException` constructior you can [find calling method using reflection](http://geekswithblogs.net/opiesblog/archive/2006/06/29/83654.aspx) and then use it.